# Ubuntu 18.04 Visual Glitching

Tags: 18.04, visual-artifacts

I recently noticed visual glitches occurring after keeping my computer on for longer periods of time. The glitch looks like artifacts left behind. I've also noticed some weird rendering issues where it seems to render in slightly different locations incredibly fast, making whatever is glitching look blurry. Finally, whenever it glitches, the dock seems to default to it's original size whenever the cursor hovers over it.

I recently tried to install a GNOME theme - System76's PopOS Theme. Could this be the cause. I'm also including the "important" section of logs from around when the glitch happened:

```
12:51:02 wpa_supplicant: dbus: Failed to construct signal
12:51:02 wpa_supplicant: dbus: Failed to construct signal
12:51:02 wpa_supplicant: dbus: wpa_dbus_get_object_properties: failed to get object properties: (none) none
12:51:02 systemd-rfkill: Failed to open device rfkill0: No such device
12:03:49 kernel: pcieport 0000:00:1c.0:    [ 0] Receiver Error         (First)
11:46:02 spice-vdagent: Cannot access vdagent virtio channel /dev/virtio-ports/com.redhat.spice.0
11:46:01 pulseaudio: [pulseaudio] backend-ofono.c: Failed to register as a handsfree audio agent with ofono: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.ofono was not provided by any .service files
11:45:55 spice-vdagent: Cannot access vdagent virtio channel /dev/virtio-ports/com.redhat.spice.0
11:45:53 wpa_supplicant: dbus: Failed to construct signal
11:45:50 kernel: Couldn't get size: 0x800000000000000e
11:45:50 kernel: tpm_crb MSFT0101:00: [Firmware Bug]: ACPI region does not cover the entire command/response buffer. [mem 0xfed40000-0xfed4087f flags 0x201] vs fed40080 f80
```

The glitch happened around 12:51-ish.

Hardware:
Dell Inspiron 13 5000 Service tag 55QL3C2.
Silicon POwer 480 GB SSD
7th Gen Core i5 with integrated graphics (Intel HD Graphics 620)
Intel Dualband Wireless AC 3165 network adapter

Comment: Can you please provide more details about your hardware? thanks.

Comment: I've added the requested hardware specifications.